# Migrate data from Kahadb to MKahadb

Tags: activemq-classic, kahadb, amq

I am changing from KahaDB to MKahaDB. So, distributing some of my queues to separated destinations. But i would like to migrate old queues' data to the newly created destinations. Is there anyone knows, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to migrate right now would be to create a new broker with the mKahaDB configuration you want and then network the old broker to the new one and create a subscription using the console on the new broker each of the destinations you want to drain over to the new broker, the demand would drain down the messages from the old broker.

Comment: Anyone know if this is still the case?

Comment: In general yes this is still the case. There was some effort to create import / export tools but that seems to have fizzled out.